# how can I send comment_id to a function of my plugin

Tags: comments

I want to receive `$comment_id` in my custom function in my plugin. I mean when a user submit a comment, I need to pass `$comment_id` to `add_custom_comment_page()`. How can I do that?

inside my plugin:

```
 $this->loader->add_action('comment_post',$plugin_public,'add_custom_comment_page');

function add_custom_comment_page() {

   $comment_id = comment_ID();
   add_comment_meta($comment_id, 'id', $id);

}
```

Comment: please check https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/adding-custom-fields-in-wordpress-comment-form/  link

Comment: @DharmishthaPatel my problem is if I can fetch the `$comment_id` which user sends it to wordpress, I'll be able to run my query due to the `$comment_id` in my plugin function

Comment: @steven Can you paste definition of the `$this->loader->add_action()` method?

Comment: [This](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/343940/cant-get-post-id) can be helpful.

Comment: @nmr I use boiler plate standard of wordpress plugin. `$this` refers to `define_public_hooks`

Comment: @steven Do the same as in the link I gave above. Add `$priority` and **`$accepted_args`** parameters in `loader->add_action()` and add parameters to the definition of `add_custom_comment_page()` function.

Comment: @PavelJanicek That post is about the _post_ ID. This question is about the _comment_ ID.