# Can't get ID of post that relates to the comment

Tags: hooks, comments

I added custom checkbox to the comment form. I am trying to write the post ID of this comment in the database. But without success.
I'm trying with something like this:

```
add_action( 'comment_post', 'save_chbox_in_db' );

function save_chbox_in_db() {
     $post_id = ??? // Can't get id...
     insert_to_db ( $email, $post_id ); // custom function
}
```

I tested these options:

```
global $post;
$post_id = $post->ID();

global $wp_query;
$post_id = $wp_query->post->ID;

$post_id = get_queried_object_id();

$post_id = get_the_ID();
```

As a result, I get zero or nothing. Where is the problem?
Something with "comment_post" action? Or do I make some stupid mistake?

Comment: Looking at the Codex the details for `comment_post` show `$comment_ID` is one of the properties passed to your function.  https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/comment_post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`comment_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comment_post/) hook pass to attached functions 3 parameters. The fourth parameter of `add_action()` indicates to how many parameters the attached function will be able to access.

```
add_action( 'comment_post', 'save_chbox_in_db', 10, 3 );

function save_chbox_in_db( $comment_ID, $comment_approved, $commentdata )
{
     $post_id = (int)$commentdata['comment_post_ID'];
     //
     // other code
     //
}
```

Comment: This is it! I was focused on a different path. Thank you very much!